# Selecting a basis such that the orientation is preserved

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I need to map a polygon from a 3D plane to a 2-dimensional basis, do some processing, and project the result back to 3D. The vertices in the polygon is always ordered counterclockwise and this orientation needs to be preserved in order for the 2D algorithm to work.

I create the basis $B$ by selecting 3 points $p_0, p_1, p_2 \in \mathbb{R}^3$ from the polygon and constructing in the following manner:

$$
v_0 =   \frac{p_1 - p_0}{||p_1 - p_0||}
$$
$$
v_1 = \frac{p_2 - p_0}{||p_2 - p_0||}
$$
$$
n = v_0 \times v_1
$$
$$
v_2 = \frac{n \times v_1}{||n \times v_1||} 
$$
$$
B = \{v_0, v_2\}
$$

How can I determine if the basis preserves orientation of the polygon? I've seen that the determinant is used to do this, but how do I apply this for my $2\times3$ basis matrix? Also, is swapping the columns always sufficient to change the orientation of the basis?

Edit:

Added an illustration of the vertex orientation before and after change of basis.
[image: Vertex orientation before and after change of basis]

Comment: You're mapping the polygon into a plane perpendicular to the original polygon. Did you intend to do that?

Comment: @PatrickStevens: oops, there was a typo in the formula for $v_2$, fixed.

Comment: @MorganRodgers: good question, and I'm not really sure on how this is defined. However, the polygons are used used for 3D rendering which require the vertices to be in counterclockwise order, but I'm guessing that they are CCW w.r.t. the plane the polygon is in. Also, fixed the last sentence - sorry.

Comment: Are the polygons planar? Convex? Any other useful property?

Comment: @MvG: planar, but not convex. Except from that they are planar and oriented CCW and simple (i.e. no self intersecting edges), there are no guaranteed properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming no special properties, in particular no coonvexity guarantees, you could always compute the signed area of the projected polygon using the [shoelace formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula). If that is negative, swap your basis vectors.

If your polygon is convex, then use two edges for $v_0$ and $v_1$, i.e. make the numerator e.g. $p_0-p_1$ and $p_2-p_1$. Since the angle between these will be in the range $(0,\pi)$ you can be certain that the cross product always points in a specific direction with respect to the plane of the polygon. So the end result will either *always* be correct or *always* be wrong. Work out one example and check whether you need to swap basis vectors.

(In my experience, most questions of “do I need a $+$ or a $-$ in this formula?” can be answered more easily by checking one example than by thinking about all the possible sign changes involved along the way.)